# Bootstrap-Vue Modal: How to open different modals in an V-For rendered list?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I am using Bootstrap-Vue Modals to open an "Edit" modal when clicking the "Edit" button that is attached to each item I have rendered in a list from v-for rendered list.

Each time, however, when I click on the edit button, it opens all of the modals, stacked on top of eachother with the last element in the list being the top modal.

How can I specify it to only open the modal/information for the item that is clicked to be edited?

```
//Parent Component

<div class="dataList">
 <div v-bind:key="item.id" v-for="item in this.$store.getters.data">
    <Child v-bind:item="item"></Child>
 </div>
</div>



//Child Component
<div>
      {{this.item.name}}
      {{this.item.details}}
      {{this.item.completedBy}}
      {{this.item.status}}
      <button v-b-modal.modal-1>Edit</button>
      <button v-on:click="deleteItem">Delete</button>

      <div>
        <b-modal id="modal-1" title="BootstrapVue">
          <form @submit="editItem">
              <input v-model="name">
              <input v-model="details">
              <input v-model="completedBy">
              <select v-model="status">
                  <option>Fail</option>
                  <option>Warn</option>
                  <option>Pass</option>
              </select><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" @click="$bvModal.hide('modal-1')">
          </form>
        </b-modal>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Now each modal shows the correct information (like the proper name, details, status, etc), but I just need it only the specific modal.

I imagine it has something to do with the 'v-b-modal.modal-1' but I'm not sure how to dynamically set the id of each modal...is there a way to easily set each modal id to match the item.id?

Here is the documentation for Bootstrap-Vue Modals, but I wasn't to find what I needed.

Comment: Sidenote, you don't need (and shouldn't) use `this.` in your template. It can cause issues with rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend moving the `<b-modal>` out of your `v-for`.
This way you only have one.

Then you instead set the user/item you want to edit to a variable, and utilize that in your modal to show the data for the selected user.

##### Example

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selectedUser: null,
      items: [{
          name: "Name 1",
          status: "Fail",
          details: "Details 1"
        },
        {
          name: "Name 2",
          status: "Warn",
          details: "Details 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    editUser(user) {
      this.selectedUser = user;
      this.$bvModal.show("edit-modal");
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="p-4">
  <div v-for="item in items" class="mt-3">
    {{item.name}} {{item.details}} {{item.status}}

    <b-btn variant="primary" @click="editUser(item)">Edit</b-btn>
    <b-btn variant="danger">Delete</b-btn>
  </div>
  <b-modal id="edit-modal" title="Edit User">
    <form v-if="selectedUser">
      <input v-model="selectedUser.name">
      <input v-model="selectedUser.details">
      <input v-model="selectedUser.completedBy">
      <select v-model="selectedUser.status">
        <option>Fail</option>
        <option>Warn</option>
        <option>Pass</option>
      </select><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

If you want to keep the modal inside your `v-for`, you will have to give it a unique `id`. If you item has one i would recommend using that, otherwise you can use the `index` from the v-for.

##### Simplified example

```
<div v-for="item in items">
  <button v-b-modal:[`edit-modal-${item.id}`]>Edit Item</button>
 
  <b-modal :id="`edit-modal-${item.id}`">
    <!-- Modal Content-->
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

Comment: Just noticed you have the modal in a child component. This means if you want to use the first example, you'd have to move the modal out of the component and do an `$emit` when clicking the edit button to let the parent know to show the modal. So the second example might be easier to implement for you.

Comment: The simplified example did the trick. I just used the v-for index and passed it to the id of b-modal and the button v-b-modal to properly id and open the correct modal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One of the most quick way but maybe not the best is Conditional Rendering the modals.

You can toggle the active modal number/index when the Edit is clicked by setting a prop/data/var as activeModal: 1 or n.

Then at the section where you iterate modals you can use v-if directive for modal like: `<v-modal v-if="activeModal">` that'd be one way to ignore/not render other modals but would cost re-rendering on each Edit click.

Best/Final solution would be to vue-portal the content to a single universal modal.